# Change InnerHtml of a <p> element

Tags: html, watin

Using WatiN project, how can I modify the `InnerHtml` of a `Para` element? That property seems to be read-only for Para and many other elements.

Comment: What you're wanting to do isn't something that is within scope/purpose of WatiN.  You'll need to do something using JavaScript / JQuery / something to manipulate the DOM.  I haven't tried BergBrains method of changing, but along those lines is what you're looking for.

Comment: @OCary: Ah, I thought WatiN was targeted at automating website testing. Many big sites (such as mail.yahoo.com and outlook.com) use InnerHtml property of a <div>, <p> and other element to let you edit/show formatted text. This means I won't be able to test any of those websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when define browser as IE type then use this code

```
 Frame fram1 = browser.Frame(Find.ById("frame_id"));

 Frame frame = fram1.Frame(Find.By("frameBorder", "0"));

 frame.ElementWithTag("body", Find.Any).SetAttributeValue("innerText","your text");
```

Comment: this codes used for input text into text editor in html with <p> tag in frame,i searched for this solution for my question 2 month